# tkinter : How to create a custom widget having a listbox that can appear and disappear over another widget without moving the other widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I had earlier posted a question on "[how to create a listbox that can appear and disappear over another widget without moving the other widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811921/tkinter-how-to-create-a-listbox-that-can-appear-and-disappear-over-another-wid)". Bryan Oakley answered my question and provided very helpful explanation and pointers.

Presently, I am looking at the next level scenario to my previous  question. That is, I want to customize a new widget that consist of a label and a listbox. It's listbox should appear and disappear in front of surrounding widgets when the new widget is clicked by a mouse pointer and the surrounding widget's position must not change. I have tried to apply what I learned previously and modified my earlier code to try to achieve my goal. My code is shown below.

The problem I am having is the listbox of mythe custom widget only appear within the frame of the custom widget (green) even though I used the `.place` layout manager. Bryan previously wrote that

> `place` doesn't affect other children of the same parent.

In this case, how should I restructure my code and widgets such that the listbox in a custom widget, when it appears, would appear in front of neighboring widgets of the custom widget? In my code, I would like the listbox to appear in front of `self.label2`, defined in `class 'App'`, when `self.newwidget` is clicked.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    import tkinter as tk # Python 3 tkinter modules
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk # Python 2 tkinter modules

class NewWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, lb_values):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background='green', borderwidth=10,
                          pady=30)
        # Initialise local variable
        self.toggle = True
        # Create widgets of NewWidget
        self.label1 = tk.Label(
            self, text='Click me to see Names of Famous Folks')
        self.lbframe = tk.Frame(self, background='orange', borderwidth=10)
        self.lbframe.list= tk.Listbox(self.lbframe, height=5, width=10)
        # Put values into listbox
        for item in lb_values:
            self.lbframe.list.insert(tk.END, item)
        # Manage widgets layout
        self.label1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.lbframe.list.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        # Set widget bindding
        self.label1.bind("<Button-1>", self.ShowHideListbox)

    def ShowHideListbox(self, event):
        if self.toggle: # Show
            self.toggle=False
            self.lbframe.place(
                in_=event.widget, x=0, rely=1, relwidth=1.0, anchor="nw")
        else: # Hide
            self.toggle=True
            self.lbframe.place_forget()


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background='pink')

        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text='Welcome!')
        nlist = ['Peter', 'Scotty', 'Walter', 'Scott', 'Mary']
        self.newwidget = NewWidget(self, nlist)
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, height=10,
                               text='The World of Famous Folks! Revealed!',)

        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', pady=10)
        self.newwidget.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.label2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.label2.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300")
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the listbox appear on top of the neighboring widgets I had to do two things:

1) Change the master widget of the frame containing the listbox in the `NewWidget` class:

```
self.lbframe = tk.Frame(self, background='orange', borderwidth=10)
```

becomes

```
self.lbframe = tk.Frame(parent, background='orange', borderwidth=10)
```

so that it has the same master as the neighboring widgets.

2) Create the `NewWidget` instance after all the other widgets in the `App` class:

```
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background='pink')
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text='Welcome!')
        nlist = ['Peter', 'Scotty', 'Walter', 'Scott', 'Mary']
        # self.newwidget = NewWidget(self, nlist) # former position
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, height=10,
                               text='The World of Famous Folks! Revealed!',)

        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', pady=10)
        self.label2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.label2.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.newwidget = NewWidget(self, nlist)
        self.newwidget.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

Comment: Excellent! It works. Can you explain the logic for the 2nd step?

Comment: I think it's because the widget created last is "higher" than the one created before (if they overlap). I first thought to use the `lift` method on `self.newwidget`, to put it in front of all its neighbors, but somehow it prevented me to click on the label to display the listbox. So instead I tried to create it last and it worked.